# Django templates - find if at least one item from a list appears in other list

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

Let's say I have two lists of strings or integers. I'd like to check if any element from the first list appears in the second one and show something ONLY ONCE if that condition is NOT met. If I do `for` loop twice I won't get the desired result - item which I'd like to display will show up multiple times:

```
# I send this from view to template

b = [{'id':1}, {'id':2}, {'id':3}, {'id':4}, {'id':5}]
d = [{'id':5}, {'id':6}, {'id':7}, {'id':8}]

# In template

{% for a in b %}
  {% for c in d %}
    {% if not a.id == c.id %}
      this will be displayed multiple times
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I display something only once here? Is this a practical way of checking things like this at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can argue if the above belongs in a template at all, but if you can't perform this comparison in a view use a [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

Comment: Ok, I see... Will try with templatetag. Thanks!